# Get category name by id using id from other table. Django

Tags: python, django

first I want to say that I am VERY begginer. I have two django models: Article and Category. In Article 4 fields, in Category 2 fields. Every article has to be assigned to category (like 'Science', 'Politics'). Article has only category ID and I want to get the category name from Category table. Example models:

Models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    article_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    category_id = models.SmallIntegerField()

class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

Views:

```
def index(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('main.html',{'articles':articles}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I can get article_id, title, content, and category_id in the template but I don't know how to get category_name from Category model using category_id from Article. Probably method has to be written in Article class and then used in the template. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. You should use a ForeignKey.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    ...
```

Then, when you have an Article object, you can access the attributes of a Category this way :

```
article.category.name
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. But let's suppose for a second that I would like to do it using IntegerFields, not ForeignKey (which I won't, it's just 100% theoretically). In PHP i would access Category class variable and use is SELECT. Like "SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE category_id = $category". How would I do it in Django? I suppose some for loop?

Comment: Category.objects.get(id=article.category_id) Cannot be simplier :)